# How do I count nil values in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, count, null

Assuming I have a model named "Person" & that person is defined by name, age, gender & race.

How do I iterate through the model to find out which values are nil?

For example:

name: peter

age: 34

gender: nil

race: nil

--Nil count: 2--

I understand I would have iterate through each field, do a +1 if value if nil & output the total value.

Thanks for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your instance is `p` then:

```
nils = p.attributes.values.select(&:nil?).count
```

will give you the number of `nil` attributes.